# Score function from RandomizedSearchCV gives different results on the same data set

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a RandomizedSearchCV using several pipelines (scaling, imputing, one-hot-encoding) to perform hyperparameter optimization for a random forest. I fit the model on my training data set and have been then using the `model.score()` function to assess its performance. Strangely, every time I run the `model.score()` on the SAME data set, it gives a different result.

My understanding of RandomizedSearchCV is that it saves the best estimator and then uses that for for the `score()` function. I've also tried to save the best estimator separately and using that for `score()` but the same thing happens (different score results). Why the different results on the same data set and what I assume is the same random forest??

Here is some dummy code that reproduces the error. My real data set is much larger:

Dummy data set:

```
# create training data set:
data_X_trainvalid = {'Temp': [23.2, 30, 'NaN', 26.5, 32, 26.6, 24.7, 19.5, 28.9, 29, 
                             15, 23, 28.8, 31.3, 'NaN'],
                    'RH': [85, 63.5, 75, 94.3, 84, 76, 'NaN', 58, 'NaN', 84.5, 
                          64, 75, 83, 90, 77.4],
                    'Precip' : [0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 12, 'NaN', 8, 0, 0,
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
                    'SoilWC': [30, 'NaN', 33, 25, 35, 40, 'NaN', 27, 28, 30,
                              29, 28, 'NaN', 32, 29],
                    'Week': [30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32,
                            32, 32, 30, 31, 32]}
X_trainvalid = pd.DataFrame(data_X_trainvalid)
y_trainvalid = np.array([2.1, 3.3, 4, 3.5, 1.8, 2.3, 2.8, 3.1, 4, 2.6,
                        2.8, 2.3, 1.9, 2.5, 3])

# create test data set:
data_X_test = {'Temp': [25.6, 'NaN', 24.3, 28.8],
                    'RH': ['NaN', 84.5, 93, 88],
                    'Precip' : [0, 0, 4, 'NaN'],
                    'SoilWC': [30, 33, 40, 29],
                    'Week': [30, 31, 32, 30]}
X_test = pd.DataFrame(data_X_test)
y_test = np.array([3.2, 2.6, 2.8, 1.9])
```

Pipelines and model fitting:

```
np.random.seed(22)

num_features = ['Temp', 'RH', 'Precip', 'SoilWC']
cat_features = ['Week']

# create preprocessors for numeric and categorical features:
numeric_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('imputer', IterativeImputer(sample_posterior = True, random_state = 356))
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='error', drop = 'first')),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'))
 ])

# creat preprocessor for data set:
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, num_features),
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, cat_features)
])

# create random forest pipeline
rf_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 545))
])

# create parameter search guidelines:
param_dist = {
    'model__n_estimators'  : scipy.stats.randint(low=5, high=20), 
    'model__max_depth'     : scipy.stats.randint(low=2, high=4) 
}

# create randomized search CV
random_search_trial = RandomizedSearchCV(rf_pipeline,
                                 param_distributions= param_dist,
                                 n_iter = 10,
                                 cv = 5,
                                 scoring = 'r2',
                                 verbose = 1,
                                 random_state = 454)

# fit the model
random_search_trial.fit(X_trainvalid, y_trainvalid)
```

Then, when I go to score the final model:

```
random_search_trial.score(X_trainvalid, y_trainvalid)
0.2552026143031859
```

And when I run the same thing again, I get:

```
random_search_trial.score(X_trainvalid, y_trainvalid)
0.2666137085384277
```

And again:

```
random_search_trial.score(X_trainvalid, y_trainvalid)
0.15377594868398703
```

Should they not give the same result since it's the same model being evaluated with the same data set? (The result is the same if I do this on the Test data set.)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I discovered the part of the code that was responsible for the strange behaviour I was observing. It turns out the argument `sample_posterior = True` in the IterativeImputer was causing the issues. From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html) I didn't totally understand how/why this was happening, but removing the argument solved the problem.